# QLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from inform)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

I got an error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lar1 and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

when I replace DB_HOST with localhost an error will appear

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lar1 and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

how to solve it?

here my code :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:oZx2D46tQg+pkzmsQ87ZM+GPvM1D8KXzEuVQN22iPCM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lar1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=27b67366036449
MAIL_PASSWORD=746d4c1cce5a90
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Example

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Have you check if your mysql is up? Is it connecting using a database tool like Heidi, DBeaver?

Comment: You are right, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `.env` file, change `DB_HOST` from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`

and then

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lar1 and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:670
    666|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    667|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    668|         // lot more helpful to the develope...

Comment: Use this code in your route and check database Connection First.

use Illuminate\Database\Connection;

Route::get('/', function () {

    // Test database connection
    try {
        DB::connection()->getPdo();
        echo "Connected successfully to: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        die("Could not connect to the database. Please check your configuration. error:" . $e );
    }

    return view('welcome');
});